# Closing Browser Tab not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript

I am trying to close the tab using script, but it's not working.

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnClose">Close</button>
```

```js
$('#btnClose').click(function() {
  var newWindow = window.open('https://localhost:44384/MasterUpdate/Index/1', '_self', ''); 
  window.close(newWindow);
});
```

The URL I am using is for testing purposes only. In my code I manually manage it using this:

```csharp
string referer = Request.Headers["Referer"].ToString();  
ViewBag.GetCurrentURL = referer;
```

I have tried so many ways but they didn't work for me.

```js
javascript:window.open('','_self').close();
window.top.close();
window.close();
```

Comment: I'm confused, you're opening a new window then immediately closing it...? What's the expected behaviour? If you're trying to close the current window while opening a new tab, then that's not possible. You can only close windows you have programmatically opened, not the original window.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yes I am Opening this page `https://localhost:44384/MasterUpdate/Index/1` from **HEADER MENU**, do stuff like UPDATE, then on the same page I have CLOSE Button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Rory pointed out, there are few conditions when window.close() works.

Below is the excerpt from this link:

[close browser tab/window](https://www.thesitewizard.com/javascripts/close-browser-tab-or-window.shtml)

Note that window.close() will only work under the following conditions:

On all modern browsers, the web page to be closed must be the first in that window/tab's session history. That is, if you hit the Back button on the browser, you will not go to a previous page in that window/tab because there is none.

You can easily accomplish that by opening that page either with JavaScript, for example, by using window.open(), or through a link that has a target="_blank" attribute. You can find example code for the former in the demo below, and the latter in the article on opening links in a new window or tab.

If you only test your code in an old browser (eg, old versions of Chrome or Firefox, or any version of Internet Explorer), you will end up with the mistaken impression that it works fine even if the above conditions are not true. Newer browser versions impose these restrictions for security (and other) reasons.

Modern browsers will also resist your attempt to trick them into thinking that an existing window/tab was opened with JavaScript when it was not. Some older versions fell for such trickery, but these methods should no longer work in the current versions of Chrome and Firefox.

Also, for tab/window must be opened via window.open() for window.close(0 to work.

Answer (score 0):

If you will to close the tab you've created with `window.open` you just have to store the new tab into variable and then use `.close()` method of this variable when you want to close it.
Short example:

```js
const newWindow = window.open('');

setTimeout(() => newWindow.close(), 1000);
```

This example shows how to create new window and then close it after 1 sec.
If you want to manualy close the tab, just call `newWindow.close()` function wherever you want.